# Can't unit test redux-saga with selector function using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, redux-saga

**Problem Explanation:**

I want to unit test a redux-saga using Jest. I'm doing this the way it is described in the example provided within the redux-saga docs: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html

Within my Saga I'm calling a selector function `selectSet` that returns a specific object from the application store:

```
export const selectSet = state => state.setStore.set
```

In my saga I'm trying to yield this selector function:

```
import { put, select } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { selectSet } from '../selectors'

export function* getSet() {
  try {
    const set = yield select(selectSet)
    yield put({ type: 'SET_SUCCESS', payload: { set } })
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: 'SET_ERROR', payload: { error } })
  }
}
```

Within my test there is no valid application store so I'd have to mock the function to return the expected object:

```
import assert from 'assert'
import * as AppRoutines from './AppRoutines'
import { put, select } from 'redux-saga/effects'

describe('getSet()', () => {
    it('should trigger an action type "SET_SUCCESS" with a payload containing a valid set', () => {
        const generator = AppRoutines.getSet()

        const set = {
          id: 1,
          slots: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }],
        }

        const selectSet = jest.fn()
        selectSet.mockReturnValue(set)

        // Saga step 1
        const actualFirst = generator.next().value
        const expectedFirst = select(selectSet)

        assert.deepEqual(
          actualFirst,
          expectedFirst,
          'it should retreive a valid set from the store using the selectSet selector'
        )
    })
})
```

However - if I assert the saga to return a specific generator value using `deepEqual` and my mocked function, it expects my selector function to have the original `selectSet` constructor. But since I'm mocking the function with jest.fn() the constructor is actually equal to `mockConstructor` - which makes my test fail:

```
Expected value to deeply equal to:
    {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "SELECT": {"args": Array [], "selector": [Function mockConstructor]}}
Received:
    {"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "SELECT": {"args": Array [], "selector": [Function selectSet]}}
```

**Question:** How can I make an assert.deepEqual containing a mock function without conflicting constructor types?

**Alternative Question:** Is there a way to make my assertion expect a `mockConstructor` instead of the actual `selectSet` constructor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not need to mock the selector at all, as in a saga test of this nature, the selector is never actually called, instead you are testing the declarative instructions that are created for the redux saga middleware to act upon are as you expect

This is the instruction that the saga will create `{"@@redux-saga/IO": true, "SELECT": {"args": Array [], "selector": [Function selectSet]}}`, but as the middleware is not running during this test scenario `selectSelect` will never actually get called

If you need to mock results that your selector returns for your action, then you do so by passing the mock data into the next step...

```
    const set = {
      id: 1,
      slots: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }],
    }

    // Saga step 1
    const firstYield = generator.next().value
    assertDeepEqual(firstYield, select(selectSet))

    // Step 2 - successful so dispatch action
    // mock data from the previous yield by passing into this step via `next(stubbedYieldedData)`
    const secondYield = generator.next(set).value
    assertDeepEqual(secondYield, put({type: 'SET_SUCCESS', payload: {set} }))
```

Comment: Thanks alot @alechill. You really saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

We can pass the mock store in a fake store as below. Below are the sample selector and generator function along with its test.

**Selector**

```
const authSelector = (state) => state.authReducer || initialState;
```

**Saga Generator function**

```
export function* getAuthToken(action) {
  try {
    const authToken = yield select(makeSelectAuthToken());
  } catch (errObj) {}
}
```

**Test Case**

```
    import { runSaga } from 'redux-saga'

    const dispatchedActions = [];

    const fakeStore = {
        getState: () => ({ authReducer: { auth: 'test' } }),
        dispatch: (action) => dispatchedActions.push(action)
      }

     await runSaga(fakeStore, getAuthToken, {
        payload: {}
     }).done;

expected case you can write here below this
```